# error with computed property

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

i'm following the how do i series for lightswitch, and converting the code as i go from VB to C#

i'm getting stuck on a computed property that is multiplying two fields and returning the result

the error is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal?' to 'decimal'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)".

i'm not sure why i would need a cast since they are both of the same type

```
thanks,
Jason
```

VB Code

```
Private Sub LineItemTotal_Compute(ByRef result As Decimal)
      result = Me.Quantity * Me.Price
End Sub
```

C# Code

```
 private void LineItemTotal_Compute(ref decimal result)
  {
      result = this.Quantity * this.Price;
  }
```

[image: line item total screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your properties are `decimal`**`?`**s (nullable).

As the error states, you cannot implicitly convert a nullable decimal to an ordinary (non-nullable) decimal.

Instead, you can write `?? 0` to coalesce to `0` if it's null.
However, you should consider making the other columns non-nullable as well to avoid the issue altogether.

Comment: this solved the problem, thanks for the suggestion               partial void LineItemTotal_Compute(ref decimal? result)
        {
            result = this.Quantity * this.Price;
        }